# Filter API Data Based on Array Of Strings

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to filter out data from fetch of an external API (CoinMarketCap) in React.

I only want the data for a specific set of tickers, but after numerous attempts I can't seem to get it to work correctly.  I feel like this should be an easy fix, but can't seem to figure it out.

```
getData = () => {
      const tickers = ["btc", "xrp", "eth", "ltc", "bch", "etc", "str", "xmr", "nxt", "zec", "rep", "dash"];
      fetch(`https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => data.filter(d => tickers.includes(d.symbol)))
      .then(results => console.log(results)
    )
```

But it's logging out an empty array.  Any ideas?

Comment: If you are receiving data from the above API, then your `array#filter` callback should be `filter(d => tickers.includes(d.symbol.toLowerCase()))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each `then()` needs a `Promise` or any thenable function. problem is that `Array.prototype.filter()` is not a promise and not resolving anything (it's not async function). you should write this:

```
getData = () => {
      const tickers = ["btc", "xrp", "eth", "ltc", "bch", "etc", "str", "xmr", "nxt", "zec", "rep", "dash"];
      fetch(`https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data.filter(d => tickers.includes(d.symbol))))
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were getting the data from fetch, add toLowerCase() to the d.symbol

`tickers.include(d.symbol.toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a CORS issue.  I had to move the fetch to my backend and called from REACT component.  Working fine now.  Thanks.